# KDB - Creating a dictionary from table columns to overcome the 8 function argument limitation?

Tags: kdb

As I'm scaling up code, I find myself needing to send more and more pieces of data to a function in order to correctly process and calculate a forecast.

I am at a fork now where to continue I need to either concatenate several column values as a large string or symbol (pretty confident I can do that but looks like a pain to maintain) vs. creating a dictionary (which I understand is best practice) to pass to my functions.

For example, I have a table with data that uses inputs as function variables to calculate and return a temporal array of data (which eventually gets ungrouped)

Using the example below which uses a field called Call_Function which has the function name in it, I want to pass several other variables (i.e.tok9, tok10, tok11,etc.)

```
//working function with 8 ordered arguments
applyFcast:{[t] update fcast: first[Call_Function]'[tok1;tok2;tok3;tok4;tok5;tok6;tok7;tok8] from t where not null tok1, 0= count each fcast};
updateTable: applyFcast ::;   //run function
t: updateTable over t;  //converge over table t
t: ungroup t;
```

I'm at a point where I am looking at creating a dictionary similar to below

```
dictArguments: {[t] exec tok1, tok2, tok3, tok4, tok5, tok6, tok7, tok8, tok9, tok10, tok11 from t}; 
applyFcast:{[t] update fcast: first[Call_Function]'[dictArguments] from t where not null dictArguments[tok1], 0= count each fcast};


updateTable: applyFcast dictArguments ::;   //run functions in order
t: updateTable over t;  //converge over table t
t: ungroup t;
```

Does anyone have a good example of how to create a dictionary to pass to a function based on numerous existing table columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work from the example you used in a prior question, if you want to take table the following table

```
q)show t:flip `id`seg`aa`bb`cc`Uknown`Call_Function!(`AAA`AAA`AAA`BBB`CCC;1 2 3 1 1;1500 0n 400 40 900;0n 200 30 40 0n;0.4 0.25 0n 0n 0.35;`bb`aa`cc`cc`bb;`Solvebb`Solveaa`Solvecc`Solvecc`Solvebb);
id  seg aa   bb  cc   Uknown Call_Function
------------------------------------------
AAA 1   1500     0.4  bb     Solvebb
AAA 2        200 0.25 aa     Solveaa
AAA 3   400  30       cc     Solvecc
BBB 1   40   40       cc     Solvecc
CCC 1   900      0.35 bb     Solvebb
```

and apply your `Call_Function`'s by passing the `aa`, `bb`, and `cc` variables as a dictionary slices rather than as three separate parameters then you can define your `Call_Function`'s as

```
q)Solvebb:{[d](d[`aa]%d[`cc])*(1-exp(neg d[`cc]*1+til 5))};
q)Solveaa:{[d](d[`bb]+d[`cc];d[`bb]*d[`cc])};
q)Solvecc:{[d](d[`aa]+d[`bb];d[`aa]*d[`bb])};
```

Then instead of using *each both* (`'`) you can use `each` on a an intermediate table consisting of only the columns `aa`, `bb`, and `cc`

```
q)ungroup update result:first[Call_Function] each ([]aa;bb;cc) by Call_Function from t
id  seg aa   bb  cc   Uknown Call_Function result
---------------------------------------------------
AAA 1   1500     0.4  bb     Solvebb       1236.3
AAA 1   1500     0.4  bb     Solvebb       2065.016
AAA 1   1500     0.4  bb     Solvebb       2620.522
AAA 1   1500     0.4  bb     Solvebb       2992.888
AAA 1   1500     0.4  bb     Solvebb       3242.493
AAA 2        200 0.25 aa     Solveaa       200.25
AAA 2        200 0.25 aa     Solveaa       50
AAA 3   400  30       cc     Solvecc       430
AAA 3   400  30       cc     Solvecc       12000
BBB 1   40   40       cc     Solvecc       80
BBB 1   40   40       cc     Solvecc       1600
CCC 1   900      0.35 bb     Solvebb       759.3735
CCC 1   900      0.35 bb     Solvebb       1294.495
CCC 1   900      0.35 bb     Solvebb       1671.589
CCC 1   900      0.35 bb     Solvebb       1937.322
CCC 1   900      0.35 bb     Solvebb       2124.581
```

Comment: Thanks again Jorge, I just realized what was going on, i though Matthew had posted this for reference but I now I see what you added.  I'll soak on this over night but the dictionary slices should be right up my alley.  Thoughts on concatenating a bunch of items into a long, delimited string and then parsing inside the function?

Comment: Thanks Jorge, this makes sense. I was not familiar with the term dictionary slice but what you described makes sense. This is exactly what I was after. Related question regarding `each`, - due to the requirement to calculate **seg** in a specific order by **id,**  would I ever be able to leverage `peach` for parallel processing?  i.e. thread off each **id** and all their **seg** and calculate them in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Potentially stupid question, but have you tried just using an `each` on the table with a function?

Tables are just lists of dictionaries, and when you index into them you get the dictionary at that point. For example:

```
q)t: ([] a: 5 ? 10; b: 5 ? 10)
q)t 0
a| 1
b| 4
```

So if we have a table with nine columns

```
q)t: ([] c1:5?10; c2:5?10; c3:5?10; c4:5?10; c5:5?10; c6:5?10; c7:5?10; c8:5?10; c9:5?10)
q)t
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9
--------------------------
9  5  9  8  4  3  5  5  8 
7  2  0  5  2  7  6  4  1 
6  3  0  2  8  8  4  2  7 
6  9  0  8  0  2  1  7  2 
4  5  9  6  5  1  3  8  4
```

and a function `f` that you want to act on it, you can just do the following:

```
q)f: {(x `c1) + x `c9}
q)f each t
17 8 13 8 8
```

Would this work for you, or have I misunderstood the question a bit?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm wrapping my head around what you've done here. There is definitely a lot of context I've not shared in the above. Effectively I have a lot of numbers and string data which my rather lengthy function parses through to determine how to process the line. The functions have a lot of If and Cond based on the permutation of the string and numeric data. This link may be a helpful reference [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163687/kdb-referencing-functions-from-a-table[link]  I'll add another comment in a moment as well.

Comment: Matthew, I added an image snippet here. [link] https://imgur.com/HdfZO8U to provide a sample.  Effectively, each row are variable inputs for a function used to generate an array of time series data. Note each row is a segment that is dependent on the result above it.  Effectively, I want a list/dictionary for each row to pass to a function which will return this array in a `$float column. The need for more function inputs is to manage the termination point of (ie....do until cumulative value, specific date, incremental months, etc)

Comment: .... Effectively a list of these would work but I was thinking as a dictionary I could then call the appropriate col name within the function if that makes sense.  The data is all parsed out of a space delimited string using {" " vs x} so I could put it all back together with these additional values and pass the string over which was my next step.

Comment: So you're doing `first[Call_Function]`, does this just evaluate to a single function? (Or just a single function name, even?)

Comment: That is correct, there is a field in the table named Call_Function that contains the the name of the function each row is calling. That bit is now working great.  The challenge is I need to pass other criteria into these functions such as cumulative values, dates, and cumulative months from the previous segment which are basically constraints (do until cumulative value = XXX, incremental time period = XXX months, or do until a specific date then terminate and move to the next segment. Its a lot of permutation management.

Comment: .... now I'm passing more than 8 arguments into these functions.  At present, I am thinking of creating field with all these values as function arguments concatenated into a single  delimited string which I would have to parse inside each function. I would just have to make sure I knew the position for each value in the string. I was thinking of passing a dictionary by row would allow me to reference the variable inside the function (and add more items as needed down the road as things arise.) There are a lot of constraint permutations on a few basic functions if that makes sense.